# Prove that if integral of $f$ around any closed disk in $U$ is $0$ then $f$ is holomorphic in $U$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know goursats theorem says that if integral of $f$ over any triangle in U is $0$ then f is locally integrable in U and hence by Moreras 
theorem is holomorphic in U. But here I need to show that if f is continuous in U and $\int f dz$ around any disk in U open set is $0$ then f is holomorphic in U. The only thing I can think of is to somehow go from disks to triangles and then invoke moreras theorem but am not sure how to do that. Any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, if the integral of $f$ over some curve $\gamma$ is not zero, you can find a point inside the region contoured by $\gamma$ such that the integral of $f$ over the border of a disk centered in this point is not zero too... So, you get a contradiction.

I can think of a problem here: if there is a region in $U$ where the function f is not holomorphic, then your disk might be inside this region. And, by accident, the value of the integral could be zero...